# Braintree Payment Gateway - integrate with Classic ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, asp-classic, braintree

I have a legacy Classic ASP site that want to use Paypal Braintree Payment Gateway (currently using Barclays ePDQ).

I note that there is no direct support for Classic ASP with Braintree so I guess that leave me looking at .Net for the server side of things?

Should I be looking at coding some sort of web service in C# that handles the server side elements of Braintree (Client Token Generation, raising transaction etc) and then look at calling that web service from within the Classic ASP pages via WinHttp or similar? Or create .aspx pages that I can call from the .asp pages?

Alternatively anyone done an integration with similar ancient code?!

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully setup a a pretty basic integration using a classic asp site.
I setup a very simple .net page that receives the transaction parameters from a classic asp POST, then fires the transaction, then forwards the transaction id to a classic ASP page on success - if it fails it sends the failure message to an classic error handling page.

So it works as kind of a proxy, A bit messy, but works fine.

Comment: Derrick - cheers for the reply - I had started down the road of creating a dll in C# to do the communication and then using that dll in my classic ASP pages - what you have done sounds a lot easier! How about generating the client token etc in your classic asp page first? Would you mind sharing some of your code or providing a little more detail? Thanks again!